# How can a popup window store additional field value in odoo?

Tags: odoo

According to scenario , i need, when user click button from main view (model name ='StudentRegistration') to open a new popup window. New opened window select drop down list option and save it into main model e.g 'StudentRegistration'.

how can i do  this operation where popup window is opening.?

Comment: Please edit your question and add: 1. Your code/your attempts 2. Your input, current output and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Create an intermediate model. Add all your required fields to this model. Create a form view for this model. Call this view on a button click. While saving this form view, access your main model and add data from here to main model.

EDIT: To call a view from button use like this:

```
<button name="%( view ID )d" string="Documents" context="{'default_cases':active_id}" type="action" />
```

Comment: According to scenario, I have two buttons (Prescribed , Referred to) on header portion of form view (view mode). when i click 'Referred to' button then open a new popup window , from there use select option and save it to already created record, it means record already exist just need to update that record with new value from popup window.
Both view using one same 'model'

default_get() ?

Comment: To my knowledge, you can not open a new form view of the same model from that models form view.

Comment: Is it possible to send record id from main view to popup window and then update record with new field define in popup window and result appear on form view (view mode) ?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Use context to pass field values... Like I used. Here 'cases' is my Many2one field to the main model. active_id will represent the current ID of main model